# Skydrive Windows app will not connect to Windows Live servers

Tags: onedrive, .net-4.0

Similar to a problem I experienced with TurboTax 2011 during an attempt to connect to their online payment servers, the Windows Skydrive application appears to be having an issue with connecting to the Live servers after I install the program. Having successfully installed it before, I know that the application should prompt me to log in after install, but instead, I am given a blank white window. I hit F5 a few times suspecting that this frame is actually an embedded browser window, and I saw a brief flash of a message about broken JavaScript support. I saw the same thing happen with TurboTax, which also appeared to prompt me with an embedded browser, but I am at a loss as to how to get around this issue.

I checked privileges for inbound/outbound connections in my firewall, attempted to run Skydrive as an administrator, tried setting my default browser to IE (in case my NoScript/AdBlock Firefox instance was causing problems), etc. No luck, and since this is the second time I have seen this happen, I feel like the issue may be .NET Framework/Windows related. Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The working answer was to reset my Privacy and Security settings in Windows 7 (Pro x64) at Control Panel -> Internet Options to the defaults, which are less restrictive than my custom changes. It seems that embedded IE was not able to load the JavaScript needed to generate the Windows Live form.